# How to structure my Python code?

Tags: python, multithreading, buffer, raspberry-pi

I apologize in advance for this being a bit vague, but I'm trying to figure out what the best way is to write my program from a high-level perspective. Here's an overview of what I'm trying to accomplish:

1. RasPi takes input from altitude sensor on serial port at 115000 baud.
2. Does some hex -> dec math and updates state variables (pitch, roll, heading, etc)
3. Uses pygame library to do some image manipulation based on the state variables on a simulated heads up display
4. Outputs the image to a projector at 30 fps.

Note that there's no user input (for now).

The issue I'm running into is the framerate. The framerate MUST be constant. I'd rather skip a data packet than drop a frame.

There's two ways I could see structuring this:

- Write one function that, when called, grabs data from the serial bus and spits out the state variables as the output. Then write a pygame loop that calls this function from inside it. My concern with this is that if the serial port starts being read at the *end* of an attitude message, it'll have to pause and wait for the message to start again (fractions of a second, but could result in a dropped frame)
- Write two separate modules, both to be running simultaneously. One continuously reads data from the serial port and updates the state variables as fast as possible. The other just does the image manipulation, and grabs the latest state variables when it needs them. However, I'm not actually sure how to write a multithreaded program like this, and I don't know how well the RasPi will handle such a program.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that RasPi would work that well running multithreaded programs.  Try the first method, though it would be interesting to see the results of a multithreaded program.